# Django Haystack index on multiple fields from same model

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am trying to embed elasticsearch in my Django app using `django-haystack`. I am trying to implement a user search. My user model is this:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Now, I want to search on `name` and `username` fields. I have created the following `search_indexes.py`:

```
class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, model_attr='name')
    username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='username')

    def get_model(self):
        return MyUser

    def get_updated_field(self):
        return "joined"
```

However, when I perform a search, I only get the results matching the `name` field. What am I doing wrong here? Is there some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way django-haystack works, the data inside the `document=True` field is used for a general search, and any other fields are used for individual filtering. So in your case, a search will only use the `name` field. To fix this, you'll need to use a template that specifies all the fields to be used in a search. First of all, use:

```
text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(document=True, use_template=True)
```

Then you’ll need to create a new template inside your template directory called `search/indexes/myapp/myuser_text.txt` and place the following inside:

```
{{ object.username }}
{{ object.name }}
```

See http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#handling-data for full reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you asked and it is still not working. I have 2 users: first with username as 'rachit' and name as 'rachit', second with username as 'r4chi7' and name as 'rachit'. A search for `rac` returns both users, but a search for `r4c` returns empty. :-/

Comment: oops my bad! Didn't rebuild the index! Thanks :-)