# Django-Haystack text field returns blank lines "\n\n"

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I trying to work with django-haystack(2.6.0) and solr(4.10.4) to implement two fields search. I would like to search my model by `ship` name or ship `country`(returns a list of ships from a given country) but here I have a problem if I define one field with `document=True` I get no results.
I fallowed the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#configuration) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272214/django-haystack-index-on-multiple-fields-from-same-model) and it looks fairly easy.

I have created the following `search_indexes.py`:

```
class ShipListIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

def get_model(self):
    return ShipList

def index_queryset(self, using=None):
    return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

and I created a new template inside my app that specifies all the fields to be used in a search:

```
search/indexes/myapp/shiplist_text.txt

{{ objects.ship }}
{{ objects.country }}
```

so here it's my model:

```
class ShipList(models.Model):
    ship = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    ship_class = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    ship_type = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

and the view:

```
def ship_search(request):
   results = None
   cd = None
   form = SearchForm()
   if 'query' in request.GET:
       form = SearchForm(request.GET)
       if form.is_valid():
           cd = form.cleaned_data
           results = SearchQuerySet().models(ShipList).filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()

   return render(request,
                'core/draft/search.html',
                {'form': form,
                'results': results,
                'cd': cd})
```

simple template

```
{% block search %}
{% if "query" in request.GET %}
{% for result in results %}
    {% with ship=result.object %}
        <p>{{ ship.ship }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ ship.get_absolute_url }}">{{ ship.ship }}</a></p>
    {% endwith %}
{% empty %}
    <p>There are no results for your query.</p>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
<h1>Search for posts</h1>
<form action="." method="get">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

so then I've checked solr interface `http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/myapp/query` for JSON response:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 2
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 11,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "django_ct": "core.shiplist",
        "id": "core.shiplist.1",
        "django_id": "1",
        "text": "\n\n"
      },
      {
        "django_ct": "core.shiplist",
        "id": "core.shiplist.2",
        "django_id": "2",
        "text": "\n\n"
      },
      {
        "django_ct": "core.shiplist",
        "id": "core.shiplist.3",
        "django_id": "3",
        "text": "\n\n"
    ]
  }
}
```

so this is the data stored for each ship in the search index
and I found out that the text field contains `"\n\n`

I'm guessing here is the problem maybe it should look like this:

```
"text": "USS Arizona\nUnited States"
```

so far I've tried to create search_indexs.py without `use_template`:

```
class ShipListIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, model_attr='ship')

    def get_model(self):
        return ShipList
```

and it's working fine, I can search by ship name and the query output is correct.

```
     {
        "id": "core.shiplist.5",
        "django_ct": "core.shiplist",
        "django_id": "5",
        "text": "USS Arizona"
      },
```

and at last my solrconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
 <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_36</luceneMatchVersion>
 <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler"
default="true" />
 <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler" />
 <requestHandler name="/admin" class="solr.admin.AdminHandlers" />
 <requestHandler name="/admin/ping" class="solr.PingRequestHandler">
 <lst name="invariants">
 <str name="qt">search</str>
 <str name="q">*:*</str>
 </lst>
 </requestHandler>
</config>
```

Obviously I'm missing something or I don't understand how it works?

Comment: Are you sure you want `{object*s*.property}` and not `{object.property}`? The answer you've linked uses the singular form..

Comment: Cheers mate! now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template for how the search field should be formed:

```
search/indexes/myapp/shiplist_text.txt

{{ objects.ship }}
{{ objects.country }}
```

.. you're referencing `objects` (with an s at the end). The correct name is `object`, without the extra `s`:

```
{{ object.ship }}
{{ object.country }}
```

The extra \n you're seeing is the newline at the end of the file. Save it without that and you'll avoid having an extra \n at the end of your value as well. It doesn't really matter for searchability, though.